# Nebulous C++ Compile Error

Tags: c++

Can anyone advise on this:

```
In file included from recorders/r5000channel.h:13:0,
             from recorders/r5000channel.cpp:11:
recorders/dtvchannel.h:53:18: warning: ‘virtual bool DTVChannel::Tune(const IPTVTuningData&)’ was hidden [-Woverloaded-virtual]
 virtual bool Tune(const IPTVTuningData&) { return false; }
              ^
In file included from recorders/r5000channel.cpp:11:0:
recorders/r5000channel.h:29:18: warning:   by ‘virtual bool R5000Channel::Tune(const DTVMultiplex&, QString)’ [-Woverloaded-virtual]
 virtual bool Tune(const DTVMultiplex &/*tuning*/, QString /*inputname*/)
              ^
In file included from recorders/r5000channel.h:13:0,
             from recorders/r5000channel.cpp:11:
recorders/dtvchannel.h:65:18: warning: ‘virtual bool DTVChannel::Tune(const QString&, int)’ was hidden [-Woverloaded-virtual]
 virtual bool Tune(const QString &freqid, int finetune)
              ^
In file included from recorders/r5000channel.cpp:11:0:
recorders/r5000channel.h:29:18: warning:   by ‘virtual bool R5000Channel::Tune(const DTVMultiplex&, QString)’ [-Woverloaded-virtual]
 virtual bool Tune(const DTVMultiplex &/*tuning*/, QString /*inputname*/)
              ^
In file included from recorders/r5000channel.h:13:0,
             from recorders/r5000channel.cpp:11:
recorders/dtvchannel.h:71:18: warning: ‘virtual bool DTVChannel::Tune(uint64_t, QString)’ was hidden [-Woverloaded-virtual]
 virtual bool Tune(uint64_t frequency, QString inputname)
              ^
In file included from recorders/r5000channel.cpp:11:0:
recorders/r5000channel.h:29:18: warning:   by ‘virtual bool R5000Channel::Tune(const DTVMultiplex&, QString)’ [-Woverloaded-virtual]
 virtual bool Tune(const DTVMultiplex &/*tuning*/, QString /*inputname*/)
```

r5000channel.h - https://pastee.org/rjajf

r5000channel.cpp - https://pastee.org/qangy

Comment: Can't spot any error, warnings only! What's the corresponding code?

Comment: It says a method was hidden. [I hate to link to Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+method+hiding&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS557US557&oq=c%2B%2B+method+hiding&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2302j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8), but searching for "C++ method hiding" will give you more resources than I can in this small comment.

Comment: I would ask this on the MythTV mailing list. Since you are not a C++ programmer. Perhaps a developer can help with the port.

Comment: I would love to ask on the Myth mailing list, but their politics have abolished work on this patch.  That's why I am left to try and keep it running so I don't lose my $1k investment in hardware.  Alan Nisota dropped support of it (the original developer) three years ago.  I've made great strides with this and have gotten it to compile through inductive reasoning.  I still have some warnings that I'd like to correct though.  I do not know the data structures being referred to, and so either a bit of instruction on what they are, or specific actions I should make are what I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it isn't an error but a warning. It seems your base classes contain overloaded version of the `virtual` function named `Tune`: when you override one of them, all versions in bases are hidden when using a derived object. Normally, this is unintentional and the normal approach to deal with overloaded `virtual` functions is to make the `virtual` functions `protected`, delegating to them from a `public` forwarding (and probably `inline`) function. See, e.g., the `virtual` functions in `std::num_get<...>`.

Another approach to avoid the hiding is to provide `using`-declarations together with the overrides of `virtual` functions. Personally, I prefer the forwarding approach.

The warnings shown are actually from header files. This means that either the library you are using is sloppy or you created a somewhat sloppy base class.

Here is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) showing the problem and, in a comment, the fix:

```
struct base
{
    virtual void foo(int) {}
    virtual void foo(bool) {}
};

struct derived: base
{
    virtual void foo(int) {}
    // add this: using base::foo;
};

int main()
{
}
```

When compiling the above code with I get these messages (abbreviated to only show the compiler version and the warnings):

```
$ g++ -v -c -Woverloaded-virtual overloaded-virtual.cpp
[...]
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.9.0 20131031 (experimental) (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.9.0 20131102 (experimental), GMP version 5.0.5, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 1.0.1
[...]
overloaded-virtual.cpp:4:22: warning: ‘virtual void base::foo(bool)’ was hidden [-Woverloaded-virtual]
         virtual void foo(bool) {}
                      ^
overloaded-virtual.cpp:9:22: warning:   by ‘virtual void derived::foo(int)’ [-Woverloaded-virtual]
         virtual void foo(int) {}
                      ^
```

When adding the comment, the warnings go away (as expected).

Comment: Thank you Dietmar.  I am not an experienced coder, so am unclear what you are saying should be done.  I notice that most of the errors relate to DTV (DirecTV) which will not be used for my purposes.  This is the satellite system -other- than Dish Network which is the target system.  I would like to fix these warnings if it would be fairly straightforward.  dtvchannel.h is here:  https://pastee.org/qtumd

Comment: @user3033518: In every class overriding just a subset of the `Tune()` overloads you can use `using <base>::Tune;` where `<base>` is the name of the respective base class. Doing so should stifle the warnings. Note, however, that it may also change the semantics as it changes the functions found for overload resolution.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with C to follow.  Starting with the first warning, the problem seems to be in dtvchannel.h line 53.  I believe you're saying it is hiding Tune() because it was used before, but I don't understand where to put 'using <base>::Tune;', or how to determine the class. (Sorry)

Comment: Maybe no one is willing to help anymore, but I think I understand this better now.  Starting with the warnings on dtvchannel.cpp here:  https://pastee.org/fcfnx  it is clear that Tune() is defined on line 51.  But then it is immediately redefined in lines 53, 65, and 71, all noted in my errors.  Reading Dietmar's message and doing a search I see that there is such a thing as 'protected virtual bool' so it is legal, but why would the original dev define, and then immediately redefine Tune()?  This doesn't make sense.

Comment: They are not _redefined_! The are _overloaded_, i.e., you can call `Tune()` with different parameters and the compiler will choose the best match. When _overriding_ one of these functions in a derived class, the overloads from the base class are hidden - unless you add `using Base::Tune;` in the derived class (where `Base` needs to replaced by the derived class's base class).

Comment: Of course I don't know how to determine the derived class's base class.  But guessing, maybe I need to add to r5000channel.h after public: using DTVChannel::Tune; since it's complaining about dtvchannel.h?  The mechanism is not clear for why the compiler can't just choose from the base (dtvchannel.h?) the Tune() function which best matches, and why I have to specify which to use.  But I'm sure this calls to a more complex mechanism.  This is so painful that I don't know how I'll ever fix the -Wmissing-prototypes warnings I'm getting...

Comment: @user3033518: Well, the class definition starts out with something along the lines of `class Derived: public Base { ... };`: that says that `Base` is a base class of `Derived` (in C++ there may be multiple bases but it shouldn't be too hard to find out which one is providing the `Tune()` overloads.

Comment: OK so` in r5000channel.h - https://pastee.org/rjajf which is one of the files throwing errors, it's `class R5000Channel : public DTVChannel`, so I correctly decided that DTVChannel in this case is the base.  But putting after public: `using DTVChannel::Tune;` hasn't fixed the overloaded warnings.

Comment: @user3033518: I have added an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (which would have been your job when asking a question). It shows the problem and the fix. If the fix doesn't fix your problem create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) showing the problem and post a new question.

Comment: And putting after the last include `using DTVChannel::Tune;` causes the compile to crash. (‘DTVChannel’ is not a namespace)

Comment: @user3033518: Create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)! Until there is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) posted to a Stackoverflow question (not a link to it - if it requires a link, it isn't a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) I'm not going to comment any further.

Comment: OK that took care of all my overload warnings, thanks.  And just in time I see, lol...